# Ruby on rails: Two records from different tables in one view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sqlite

I want to display information from two different tables in one page. For example, I want to show user last name from one table, and url to attached file from the second. How can I reference to the 2nd table in my view?

Comment: Is there an association between the models?

Comment: Your controllers can access all models, not only the models with the same name. Of course you expect controller "users" to get data from table "users" but this is not exclusive...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your data is going to be accessible to your views via instance variables (`@users, @files`) that are set in the controller. Just declare another instance variable `@files = File.all` and in the view iterate through the collection, which will be the instance variable `@files`, and show the url for the file, or whatever other logic you want.

Answer (score 1):

Your controllers have access to any and all db in your app. Your views have access to instance variables. So in your controller, you can do something like this:

```
@users = User.all
@files = File.all
```

Then, in your view, you can iterate over the instance variables to show what you need.